# How to Connect Frontend and Backend

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, backend

As I am a bit beginner

Could anyone help with how can I connect my Front-End (deployed on gh-pages) and backend ( deployed on Heroku) with each other

Frontend consists of simple index.html file and app.js file.
And my Backend consist of server.js file.

How should I make changes to both of them. To integrate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Some more options have popped up these days but the workflow still used in 99% of apps is:

1. Client makes HTTP request to server
2. Server receives request and does something with it
3. Server responds to the request
4. Client receives response

Remember that your backend and frontend are 2 separately running programs on different machines.

The 2 most used ways to make your front-end communicate with the backend are:

- To communicate you could make an AJAX call (an HTTP request from your javascript)
- Complete a form (a form submission send a request to where the Action attribute points)

There are quite a few more possibilities these days but these are the ones you should probably look at first :)